# Acessing JSON Information by order

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am reading information from a JSON string, and when I execute
   `console.log(record.seenTime.time.seenEpoch)`
it display the right information.

But when I use `console.log(record.seenTime.time[0].seenEpoch)`, I get an error saying :

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'seenEpoch' of undefined`.

Here is an example set of data:

```
  { 
    seenTimes: { 
      time: { 
        seenTime: '2014-09-10T20:18:32Z',
        seenEpoch: 1410380312 
      }
    } 
  }
```

Anyone know what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Why would you expect that to work? Is it an object or an array?

Comment: @SLaks It says so in the documentation. Link: [http://www.json.org/js.html]

Comment: If `time.seenEpoch` works, that means it isn't an array, and `time[0]` doesn't exist.

Comment: @user2816783 your documentation doesn't say anything about your particular JSON. Please post your string for us to be able to point to you what you do wrong.

Comment: If you're expecting several "time" objects, then it seems your problem comes from your JSON and not from the way you read it. +1 for posting your json here

Comment: added sample data in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`record.seenTimes` in this case is an Object, not an Array, you can verify that using

```
typeof record.seenTimes
```

Because of that, time[0] returns undefined.

`seenEpoch` is a property of the ONE AND ONLY time object, therefore, you access it using `record.seenTimes.time.seenEpoch`

For once, I'll recommend reading something from w3schools : [JSON Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp)

It'll show you examples of what can be stored in JSON.

EDIT :

Your sample `record.seenTimes` will not be able to store multiple time objects, as it uses the curly brackets `{}` which indicate that it's meant to store an object , if you want to be able to store multiple time objects, ie: an Array, your JSON will have to look like :

```
record {
  seenTimes: [
    {
      time: {
        seenTime: '2014-09-10T20:18:32Z',
        seenEpoch: 1410380312 
      }
    },
    {
      time: {
        seenTime: '2014-09-10T20:18:32Z',
        seenEpoch: 1410380312 
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Note the square brackets that say that seenTime holds an array.

And as [slebetman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/167735/slebetman) noted :

> Also note that in javascript, an object defined as having multiple
>   identical keys are technically invalid. But most implementations take
>   the last definition. For example, the object: {a:1,a:2,a:3} is exactly
>   the same as {a:3}. So if you don't use an array then there is only one
>   time object even if it appears twice in the JSON string.

Comment: how do you access the first time object then?

Comment: there is only one time object, you access it using : record.seenTime.time

Comment: But there might be more time objects. It's 1 or more time objects.

Comment: Also note that in javascript, an object defined as having multiple identical keys are technically invalid. But most implementations take the last definition. For example, the object: `{a:1,a:2,a:3}` is exactly the same as `{a:3}`. So if you don't use an array then there is only one time object even if it appears twice in the JSON string.